# Search then email string in text file

Tags: powershell-3.0

Every day I need to search for the figure after "SALES TOTAL:" and email it. I would love to automate this tedious task (ideally using PowerShell).

Could someone help me with an example script for this please? The script will be running on Windows Server 2012R2 with PowerShell 3.0.

[Example text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQcms.png)

Comment: Using ps command: select-string -path c:\day.log -pattern "SALES TOTAL:" I can select all lines that have "SALES TOTAL: FIGURE" I have no idea how to select the last line and email this. (I'm aware of the "Send-MailMessage" command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code works perfectly for me:

```
$finds = Select-String -Path "file path" -Pattern "text to search" | ForEach-Object {$_.Line}

Send-MailMessage -To "email.address", -From "email.address" -Subject "subject" -body $finds[-1] -SmtpServer "smtp address" here
```

Note:
`[-1]` (displays only the last line)
`ForEach-Object {$_.Line}` removes the file name and line number

Answer (score 0):

Powershell Script to Search for String:

```
###########################################################
$Path = "C:\temp"
$Text = "SALES TOTAL"
$PathArray = @()
$Results = "C:\temp\test.txt"

# This code snippet gets all the files in $Path that end in ".txt".
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.txt"” |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "“Directory"} |
ForEach-Object {
If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text) {
$PathArray += $_.FullName
$PathArray += $_.FullName
}
}
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}


##########################################################
```

And then refer to this [article](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-sending-email-with-gmail-example/) to map out the sending of the mail (as I am unsure what mail client you would be using).

Comment: I think this script will search for files that a string of text in it, then out the file names to a different directory. Useful but not quite what I'm looking for. `$Text = "SALES TOTAL"
select-string -path c:\day.log -pattern "$text" -list` is the best I can do so far which will display the first line, need the last line.